# Shiny: how do I convert \n to actual line breaks in verbatimTextOutput?

Tags: r, text, formatting, shiny

I'm trying to print formatted R code (i.e., R code that contains tabs and spaces) in my shiny App.

When I try to use verbatimTextOutput, it just smashes all the code together and replaces line breaks with "\n".

Is there a way to either:

1. Stop the conversion of line breaks in my code to "\n"
2. Convert "\n" back to actual line breaks in the app (possibly via an HTML tag?)

Or is there some other better approach to printing R code (preferably with grey background like in markdown) in a Shiny app?

Comment: please provide minimal working example

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean. You should provide some code to show the problem you describe. The following shiny app *does* result in two lines of text

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    string <- "hello\nworld"
    string
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```